# replacing values in an STL-like map

Tags: c++

I've a problem with a btree implementation of a map (from [here](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/)). My code is the following:

```c
Tree *bt = create_btree();

unsigned char *test = (unsigned char *) malloc(5);
unsigned char *test2 = (unsigned char *) malloc(5);

memset(test, 0, 5);
memset(test2, 0, 5);

memcpy(test + 0, "a\0", 2);
memcpy(test + 2, "HAM", 3);

memcpy(test2 + 0, "a\0", 2);
memcpy(test2 + 2, "FRA", 3);

(*bt)[test] = 659;
(*bt)[test2] = 999;
(*bt)[test] = 350;

int value;
unsigned char *key;
Tree::iterator iter;

for (iter = bt->begin(); iter != bt->end(); iter++) {
    key = iter->first;
    value = iter->second;

    printf("Key: ");
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%02x ", (int) key[i]);
    printf("; Value: %d\n", value);

}

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(2, (int )bt->size());

Tree::iterator it = bt->find(test);
value = (*it).second;

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(350, value);
```

As the last line of code shows, I expect `value` to be 350, because I changed the value of `test` from `659` to `350`. Also there should be only two elements inside the map but the output is the following:

```c
Key: 61 00 48 41 4d ; Value: 659
Key: 61 00 46 52 41 ; Value: 999
Key: 61 00 48 41 4d ; Value: 350
```

I pass the tree an own implemented compare function to sort the elements:

```c
struct cmpBinary {
    bool operator()(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b) const {
        //d_size is 5
        bool cmp = memcmp(a, b, d_size);
        return cmp;
    }
};

/* TYPEDEF */
typedef btree::btree_map<unsigned char*, int, cmpBinary, allocator<unsigned char*>, node_size> Tree;
```

My question is, why does the first elements data will not get replaced by the value `350`? An interesting fact is that if I delete the line `(*bt)[test2] = 999;` and insert the "third" (now second) element directly after the first, the output is as expected.

```c
Key: 61 00 48 41 4d ; Value: 350
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memcmp` returns `0` if the memory regions are equal, otherwise a negative if the first is smaller and positive if the second is bigger. When we check the template definition of the tree map we see:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value,
          typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Value> >,
          int TargetNodeSize = 256>
```

So we must provide our own `std::less` version and define what *lower than* means:

```
struct cmpBinary {
    inline bool operator()(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b) const {
        return memcmp(a, b, d_size) < 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have to use bool. Otherwise the compilation of the btree-library will fail.

Comment: What do you mean with `your own less version`.  Can I still use your code from above?

Comment: I mean the default comparator is the one that returns if the first argument is smaller than the second one. Yes the above is a valid less implementation

Comment: Okay. So a function is required which return if the first element is smaller and not an function which returns if the second argument is smaller, equal or bigger.